# Cannot go to url using ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.6

I'm using ajax to implement infinite scroll pagination in laravel but I cannot access the url while I can with the enter the url in the adress bar or via the default pagination page list.

I get `GET http://localhost:8888/gest/items?page=2 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = 1;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            page++;
            loadMoreData(page);
        }
    });


    function loadMoreData(page){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '?page=' + page,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                if(data.html == " "){
                    $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
                    return;
                }
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $(".row-items").append(data.html);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }
</script>
```

And the controller

```
public function index(Request $request, $submenu = null){
    $items = Item::paginate(5);
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $view = view('data',compact('items'))->render();
        return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
    }
    return view('layouts.gest', compact('items'), ['submenu' => $submenu]);
}
```

**EDIT**
I also tested to add

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that laravel couldn't find the view `data`